# Why does Objective-C include the full C++ type name as a string in the binary? Can I get rid of it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c++

When I add a C++ type as an Objective-C ivar, I get the full name of that type included, as a string:

```
@interface Test {
    std::vector<int> _vector;
    std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<std::string>> _map;
}

@end

@implementation Test
@end
```

Results in:

```
.L__unnamed_2:
        .asciz  "_vector"

.L__unnamed_3:
        .asciz  "{vector<int, std::allocator<int> >=\"_M_impl\"{_Vector_impl=\"_M_start\"^i\"_M_finish\"^i\"_M_end_of_storage\"^i}}"

__objc_ivar_offset_value_Test._vector:
        .long   0                       # 0x0

.L__unnamed_4:
        .asciz  "_map"

.L__unnamed_5:
        .asciz  "{unordered_map<int, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, std::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > > > >=\"_M_h\"{_Hashtable<int, std::pair<const int, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > > >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<int>, std::hash<int>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> >=\"_M_buckets\"^^{_Hash_node_base}\"_M_bucket_count\"Q\"_M_before_begin\"{_Hash_node_base=\"_M_nxt\"^{_Hash_node_base}}\"_M_element_count\"Q\"_M_rehash_policy\"{_Prime_rehash_policy=\"_M_max_load_factor\"f\"_M_next_resize\"Q}\"_M_single_bucket\"^{_Hash_node_base}}}"
```

[Compiler Explorer link](https://godbolt.org/z/ygE-GZ)—note that I'm using `-Os`.

The latter one, using `std::unordered_map`, is about 1kb. What is the purpose of this, and can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

That information is required for the type-encoding used by the Objective-C runtime, and is part of how dynamic dispatch works. It's retrievable by interrogating the runtime:

```
Ivar *ivars = class_copyIvarList([Test class], NULL);
printf("%s\n", ivar_getTypeEncoding(ivars[1]));
free(ivars); ivars = NULL;
```

In order to eliminate it, you would need to avoid placing C++ types directly in the ObjC object. You can somewhat reduce the verbosity by boxing:

```
class Box {
    std::vector<int> _vector;
    std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<std::string> > *_map;
};

@interface Test: NSObject {
    Box box;
}
@end
```

Yields

```
{Box="_vector"{vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> 
>="__begin_"^i"__end_"^i"__end_cap_"{__compressed_pair<int *, 
std::__1::allocator<int> >="__value_"^i}}"_map"^{unordered_map<int, 
std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char>, 
std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char> > >, std::__1::hash<int>, 
std::__1::equal_to<int>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const int, 
std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char>, 
std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char> > > > > >}}
```

And a pointer to a box is a bit smaller:

```
^{Box={vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >=^i^i{__compressed_pair<int *,
std::__1::allocator<int> >=^i}}^{unordered_map<int,
std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char>, 
std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char> > >, std::__1::hash<int>,
std::__1::equal_to<int>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const int, 
std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char>, 
std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char> > > > > >}}
```

And of course you can go further by making the box a `void *` and casting as needed, or possibly by hiding it behind a simpler C++ type and a pimpl (I haven't tried that approach to see if it works). But if you put C++ (or anything else) directly in an ObjC ivar, it has to store the name of the type for the runtime.